# How do I allow non-root access to Nexus 7 2013 LTE (deb) over adb and fastboot?

Tags: usb, android, non-root-user, adb

I need to access my Nexus 7 2013 LTE (deb) over `adb` and `fastboot`, but it seems that it's required to be `root` to be able to run the `adb` server to be able to access the device due to USB rules.

How can I configure udev to allow access to this device as a non-root user for `adb` and `fastboot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file at `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-nexus7-deb.rules`:

#### `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-nexus7-deb.rules`:

```
# adb protocol on nexus 7 deb/razorg:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="d001", MODE="0600", OWNER="myusername"
# fastboot protocol on nexus 7 deb/razorg
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee0", MODE="0600", OWNER="myusername"
```

Change `myusername` above to be your Linux username. Simply unplug your Android device and replug to be able to access `adb` and `fastboot` as a non-root user.